# why does set_role cause internal server error 500?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am fairly new to php and the wordpress environment. Regardless, I've set out to create a plugin that updates users' roles at set intervals using wp-cron...
However, I think I've missed out on something, since whenever I'm trying to use set_role (or add_role) it causes an internal server error 500....

The plugin I'm trying to make is for a wordpress 5.0.3 multisite, where it will only be activated on one of the sites.
Previously to activating and testing the plugin, I've created custom roles using the plugin 'Members' by Justin Tadlock.
Debugging, it seems that I'm able to get user objects with the corresponding role, but trying to change their role causes the server error.

```
// Get all users with specific role
$all_users_with_role = get_users( 'role=custom_role' );

// Go through users and update role
foreach ( $all_users_with_role as $user ) {

    $user_role = new WP_User( $user->ID ); // This works fine
    $user_role->set_role( 'new_custom_role' ); // This doesn't...
}
```

The code will show that there are users with the custom role when doing this in the loop:

```
echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user_role->user_email ) . '</span>';
```

However, using set_role, add_role, or remove_role causes the error.

Is there something I'm missing? Is it not aware of the role I'm trying to assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not allowed to comment so I'm commenting  here for now:
You should get some more debugging info, might give you a clue to whats happening and would let others help you out here.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Look for the 500 server error in the debugging log or the WP debug output and paste the information here.

Comment: Oh thanks man :)
I activated debugging and found that it throws an "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_user_by()" in the meta.php file. 
I did some digging and found that it was likely since I tried hooking and do the hook in the plugin file itself... 
I changed it so it hooks into a scheduled event instead and it works ^_^

Comment: I'm glad it worked out: googling specific errors from debugging/logs usually gives good clues or straight up fixes. There is almost always someone out there that had the same issues as you, has helped me countless times. Take care Mark!